# Text Wrap ListBox on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

How can I wrap a long text in a ListBox without using of TextBlock. My code is as follows:

```
public Sample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            quotes.Add("LooooooooooooooooooooooooooongTeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext");
            myListbox.DataContext = quotes;

}
```

quotes is a list.

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,0,12,0" Grid.Column="1">
                <ListBox x:Name="myListbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,4,10,3">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>

                 </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I have also tried with WrapPanel, but doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use a TextBlock? This is the defacto method of displaying text in a wrapping block in Windows Phone and is easily accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemsPanel` controls how ListBox arrange ListBoxItems in certain Layout. Try to define `ItemTemplate` instead of `ItemsPanel`, `ItemTemplate` controls how data in each item displayed, including whether it wrapped or not. Sorry, but I am using TextBlock here, because I can't see why avoid TextBlock. Its even very likely (haven't proved this as for now) that TextBlock is the default ItemTemplate for ListBox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListbox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,4,10,3">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This does not work in windows 8.1  The combobox appears empty.